# List item selector without item with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following list

```
<ul id='myList'>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class='item-selected'>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add class `item-over` on `mouseenter` and want to remove class `item-over` on

`mouseleave` without item which has class `item-selected`

I have tried

```
$('#myList li:not(".item-selected")')
    .mouseenter(function(){ 
         $(this).addClass('item-over'); 
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).removeClass('item-over'); 
    });
```

But unable.

How can do it?

Comment: `:hover` in css not working?

Comment: Your code works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uLYXf/. The issue may lie elsewhere in your code, possibly in the CSS for the `.item-over` rule.

Comment: whether the `li` elements are created dynamically... is the code under a dom ready handler

Comment: is it in doc ready handler? and have you included the jQuery library first? Any errors in the console of browser?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the function to make doubly sure, I'd also use `hover` to make it more exciting and fun:

```
$('#myList li').not( ".item-selected" ).hover(
     function(){ 
         $(this).addClass('item-over'); 
     },
     function() {
          $(this).removeClass('item-over'); 
     }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer should work but not working in my large scripts and dynamically created list. I did it as http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492779/2459296

Answer (score 0):

What it seems you have missed the `doc ready` handler for this, try putting it in document ready block:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myList li:not(".item-selected")').mouseenter(function(){ 
        $(this).addClass('item-over'); 
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('item-over'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer should work but not working in my large scripts and dynamically created list. I did it as http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492779/2459296

Comment: You should have mentioned earlier about it, (dynamically created).

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your code is just fine, on the event side.

look at http://jsfiddle.net/F8rxJ/

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myList li:not(".item-selected")').bind('click',function(){
        alert('xxx');            
    });

});
```

it shows you that the event is working.

try to use "hover" on your real work you try to do.

Comment: Thanks, your answer should work but not working in my large scripts and dynamically created list. I did it as http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492779/2459296

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a JavaScript for this.

```
#myList li {
    &:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

    &.item-selected,
    &.item-selected:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/xGqeE/

---

or for IE >= 8

```
#myList li {
    &:hover:not(.item-selected) {
        color: blue;
    }

    &.item-selected {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/LBULM/

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, I will try it but was finding using jquery, I did it as http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492779/2459296

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
$('#myList li:not(".item-selected")')
    .mouseenter(function(){ 
         if(!$(this).hasClass("item-selected")) //added this line
             $(this).addClass('item-over'); 
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).removeClass('item-over'); 
    });
```